# Is it possible to convert pdf to svg in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, svg

I am looking for any package in laravel which provides functionality to convert pdf to svg and, it should also provides functionality of download and store.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert 10MB PDF to SVG quickly with appropriate size for web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38329534/how-to-convert-10mb-pdf-to-svg-quickly-with-appropriate-size-for-web)

Comment: No, i want to convert in laravel.

Comment: it's the same thing.

Answer (score -1):

Laravel is just a framework built on PHP, so whatever PHP implementation is viable - it will be viable on Laravel.

I have asked a quite different question, but the answer may lead you to positive results. [Ghostscript PDF file compression using PHP's exec (Laravel on Docker)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60987289/ghostscript-pdf-file-compression-using-phps-exec-laravel-on-docker)

You can use my implementation and combine it with this: [How to convert 10MB PDF to SVG quickly with appropriate size for web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38329534/how-to-convert-10mb-pdf-to-svg-quickly-with-appropriate-size-for-web)

Good luck.

Comment: i used this package org_heigl/ghostscript , but it gives me error of InvalidArgumentException
No GS-Path set, could you help me on that., it requires ghostscript in machine or what?

Comment: Please add all relevant information to the answer instead of linking to external ressources. If you assume that this question has been answered before, flag it as a dupilcate